# Advance a UTF-8 character to the next

Tags: c, string, encoding, utf-8, glib

I want to change a UTF-8 character (which is in a gchar array), so it gets the value of the next character according to the standard. I'm using glib and I don't see a function like that. I'm thinking of a possible solution, but it would take maybe more effort and surely it wouldn't be the most efficient, as I don't know too much about encodings. Is there any library that can do that? Googling didn't help.

Comment: You'll run into trouble at code points 0x7f, 0x7ff, 0xffff, etc.  The next increment will need more space.  Best to create a new string instead of trying to do it in-place.

Comment: @Hans: Creating a new string 3 times is a lot less expensive than doing it `N` (~1 million?) times. :-)

Comment: I suspect the majority of glib/gtk programmers don't realize that sort of thing or don't bother to think about it, which is why these programs tend to be so slow and bloated...

Comment: Hey! we do think about that sort of things!=). Whatever, i consider myself a newbie glib/gtk programmer, and this is for a small program that surely will never see the light, so it's not slow, nor bloated =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is essentially just add-and-carry modulo 64. Consider the bytes of the character as "digits". You increment the last byte, and if it overflows, reset it to the smallest possible value, and increment the second-to-last byte.

For example, a simple increment:

```
e0 b0 be -> e0 b0 bf
```

An increment with single carry:

```
e0 b0 bf -> e0 b1 80
```

And an increment with double carry:

```
e0 bf bf -> e1 80 80
```

When you increment past the last character of a given size, you'll need to go to the first character of the next size, which of course can't be done in-place in the middle of a string.

Comment: Note that, whether you use my algorithm here or another, you'll need to manually skip past at least the illegal values (surrogates D800-DFFF) which are not Unicode Scalar Values. If you also want to skip past non-characters, that will be a lot more work.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer. It is what i was thinking. Anyway, i will just advance to characters 3 bytes long, and later go again to 1 byte. I will skip non-characters, but those are the ones in normal ascii and from 80 to A0, isnt?

Comment: Non-characters differ from illegal byte sequences. They include Unicode scalar values such as U+FFFE, U+FFFF, U+1FFFE, etc. U+FDD0..FDEF are also reserved as non-characters. These codepoints are legal for conversions between different UTFs and intended for internal use by applications, but not for interchange with other applications/the outside world.

Comment: Also, since you seem to be unaware, there are a number of other illegal byte sequences aside from lone UTF-8 tail bytes without a head byte. `80-BF` are all tail bytes and invalid without a head, and the bytes `C0-C1` and `F5-FF` are *illegal anywhere* in UTF-8. Also, Certain head bytes have restrictions on which tail bytes can follow them. For instance, `E0 80 80` is illegal, but `EO A0 80` is legal. Note that `ED` followed by `A0-BF` is illegal, as these encodings would represent surrogates which are not Unicode Scalar Values.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid direct byte-hacking, you could do something like this (untested):

```
gunichar c;
int len, old_len;
char buf[6];

c = g_utf8_get_char(s);
old_len = g_unichar_to_utf8(c, NULL);
c += 1;
len = g_unichar_to_utf8(c, buf);
if (len == old_len) {
  memcpy(s, buf, len);
} else {
  /* something more complex adjusting s length */
}
```

Of course writing it manually would give you more optimized code. A minor optimization to the above might use g_utf8_next_char() to get the next string position, and compute the old_len from that, instead of independently computing old_len.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like another good alternative i didn't think of

Comment: If you're unprepared to read the spec and deal with writing correct code for UTF-8, you might be better off with this answer... Even with this approach though you need to skip the surrogate range at least.

Comment: Yes, I know. But i will probably do it the other way because i like to go low-level and learn new things.